# Cannot retrieve Server Name (SNI) from ClientHello using OpenSSL 1.1.1

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, sni

On my running server (using **OpenSSL 1.1.1d**) I tried extracting the Server Name (SNI) extension from ClientHello messages using the following callback [API](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_client_hello_cb.html) by:

- Calling `SSL_client_hello_get0_ext` with the `TLSEXT_TYPE_server_name` type as done in the [repo](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/12a765a5235f181c2f4992b615eb5f892c368e88/test/handshake_helper.c#L162).
- Calling `SSL_get_servername` with `TLSEXT_NAMETYPE_host_name` [as documented](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_servername.html).

Yet nothing seems to work, the SNI is either NULL or garbage.

One thing that I noticed was that only after finishing the ClientHello callback I was able to extract it, but at that point it's too late.
Has someone encountered a similar issue?

Attaching below a minimal code sample demonstrating how I retrieve the SNI:

```
int
my_server::client_hello_cb(SSL *ssl, int *al, void *arg)
{
    my_server* server = static_cast<my_server*>(SSL_get_app_data(ssl));
    const char *sni = SSL_get_servername(ssl, TLSEXT_NAMETYPE_host_name);

    server->set_client_sni(sni);
    return 0;
}

void
my_server::create()
{
    SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx_);
    SSL_set_app_data(ssl, this);

    BIO* rbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO* wbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, rbio, wbio);

    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method());

    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);
    SSL_CTX_set_client_hello_cb(ctx, client_hello_cb, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem. Given that it behaves differently than the OpenSSL test code suggests that something essential is different in your code.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Unfortunately I cannot share the source code. But, the main flow is registering to "SSL_CTX_set_client_hello_cb" on my server and calling "SSL_get_servername" (that returns null) when the callback is invoked

Comment: I did not ask that you share your original source code. In fact, that would likely be too much code to look at. I've instead asked that you __create__ some __minimal__ code example which can be used by others to __reproduce__ the issue. A common way to do this is to strip down the original code to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem. Another way would be to create some minimal code based on the description you have in your question - and if this is not enough to recreate the problem then your question is missing essential details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Added some code sample demonstrating the basic flow, hope it might help

Comment: It might be that `SSL_get_servername` is not working inside the clienthello callback since it is more intended for the (obsolete) `tlsext_servername_callback` which comes later. But you refer specifically to `SSL_client_hello_get0_ext` not working even though it is used in the OpenSSL test code. Please use this instead in your example code and also provide more details about the claimed "garbage" it returns.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, I was using the API wrong this whole time. As it turns out the 'SSL_client_hello_get0_ext' method gives access to the unprocessed extension. Added a solution if someone needs it in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to [Steffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) for clearing stuff out.

The `SSL_get_servername` must be called directly from the server name callback, therfore not solving the original issue.

Instead, the server name extension can be parsed manually (as done [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/12a765a5235f181c2f4992b615eb5f892c368e88/test/handshake_helper.c#L162)) using `SSL_client_hello_get0_ext` directly from the client hello callback.